# Need FULL Jenkins Pipeline-As-Code documentation

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I would like to know where people do get information about such Jenkins scripted pipeline syntax as, for example:

1.

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([cron('*/5 * * * *')]),
])
```

2.

```
git(
    poll: true,
    url: 'ssh://<URL>/<repo>.git',
    credentialsId: 'XXX',
    branch: 'XXX'
)
```

I tried to use https://jenkins.io/doc/book/ and search with Ctrl+F like in html as in the PDF version of the book (https://jenkins.io/user-handbook.pdf) as well and found nothing! Searching in Google for "pipelineTriggers" points to stackoverflow or articles of other persons, but not to some *official* Jenkins sources.
I need a tutorial where I could search for the description of every element of scripted pipeline with all its possible options and their values.
Could someone please refer where everybody read about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all documented pipeline steps in [Pipeline Steps Reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/)
Also you can use [Snippet Generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator).

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the Snippet Generator earlier. As I see now, all snippets which I found in Internet come from it and not from some reference guide.